# How can I set a custom column with a boolean value when a match is found in a other table?

Tags: mysql, join, select, group-by, pivot

Hi I'm struggling with creating a custom column on when a match is found in a different table.

Table structur:

Table Contacts contains the table columns

- id
- some other columns which don't matter for my question

Table Projects contains the table columns

- id
- name

Table Matches contains the table columns

- id
- project_id (equal to project table id)
- contact_id (equal to contact table id)

The problem

So for example I want to retrieve the contacts which have a match on project number 1 and 2.
with a left join I will connect the contact information based on contact "id" which matches with the "contact_id" from the matches table.
Now I want to add a column to this contact which says that the contact is part of project 1 or/and 2

So the output should be, if a contact is present is matches table with project id 1 and/or project id 2.

Table should look like this:

Contact
id,(contact default columns not important for my question), project1, project2, etc

123,(some default columns),1,0 (for example)

What I don't want is that in the output table the same contact is present multiple times only set with different value's in project1 column or project2 column. So the contacts need to be grouped some how!
Also the amount of projects that can be present as a column should not be bound because a contact can be connected to 10 projects.

What I have come up with so fare.

```
SELECT contacts.*, (fields project1 and project2, etc. more columns when there are more matches)  
FROM contacts 
 LEFT JOIN matches on contacts.id = matches.contact_id
 LEFT JOIN projects ON projects.project_id = matches.project_id
GROUP BY contacts.id
```

Is there anybody who can help me out with this query. Because a this point I don't know anymore how to approach this problem I have tried multiple things nothing gives me the above described result.

If there need to be created more left joins then that's no problem I can implement that.

**NEW ADDED**

So I managed to get until this point, however this query shows only project1 with value true but project1 and project2 should be true in this case but it doesn't because it's grouped on the contact.id which causes to show only the first found record from the matched tabel which in this case is a connection between contact with id 1 and project id 1.

```
SELECT contacts.* , 
 IF(matches.project_id = 1, true,false ) as project1, 
 IF(matches.project_id = 2, true,false ) as project2
FROM contacts
 LEFT JOIN matches ON matches.contact_id = contacts.id
 LEFT JOIN projects ON projects.id = matches.project_id
GROUP BY contacts.id
```

When I leave out the group by it show the 2 results which are correct
first record shows project1 is true second record shows project2 is true.
Now I only need the values of project1 and project2 in one row sins the contact person is the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of those `IF`s use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT contacts.*, 
  MAX(matches.project_id = 1) as project1, 
  MAX(matches.project_id = 2) as project2
FROM contacts
 LEFT JOIN matches ON matches.contact_id = contacts.id
 LEFT JOIN projects ON projects.id = matches.project_id
GROUP BY contacts.id
```

Comment: Thanks this helped met out find the right combinations.

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    c.id,
    max(m,project_id = 1) has_project_1, 
    max(m,project_id = 2) has_project_2
from contacts c
left join matches m 
    on m.contact_id = c.id
    and m.project_id in (1, 2)
group by c.id
```

Notes:

- You don’t need to bring in the `projects` table to get the result that you want.
- You can pre-filter the join with the projects you are interested in to restrict the number of rows to aggregate.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write, read and maintain.

But actually, two left joins might be more efficient:

```
select
    c.*,
    (m1.project_id is not null) hzs_project_1,
    (m2.project_id is not null) hzs_project_2
from contact c
left join matches m1
    on m1.contact_id = c.id
    and m1.project_id = 1
left join matches m3
    on m2.contact_id = c.id
    and m2.project_id = 2
```

Comment: Thanks this helped met out find the right combinations.